# I want to refactoring this code (default parameter using non-instantiated class)

Tags: c++, refactoring, default-parameters

my_func.h

```
class MyClass{
 public:
  OtherClass otherclass;
  void func();
  void func(OtherClass others);
};
```

my_func.cpp

```
#includ <my_func.h>

void MyClass::func(){
 func(this->otherclass);
}

void MyClass::func(OtherClass others){
 if(others.value.IsObject)
   func(others.value);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <my_func.h>

int main(){
 func();
}
```

I want to refactoring this code.

I want to set default parameter, so I write code like this.

but I think there is a better way.

Comment: Your implementations of `func` are introducing new non-class functions. In order to implement the class methods use e.g. `void MyClass::func(){ ... }`.

Comment: As is, your function seems to do nothing observable...

Comment: I modify code refer to your comment.

I dont want to use override like this.

I want to set `default parameter` like `void func(Otherclass others=this->otherclass)`